# xmlhttprequest 404 error (with existing files)

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I've searched for the answer but I haven't found anything regarding this issue. My apologies in advance if I'm wrong.

Here the issue: I've got some file in the target directory let's say `file1.html, file2.ts,...` and `index.html`. Well, the line:

```
x= new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("get",file,true)
```

gets `x.status 200` only when  `file = "index.html"` while I get 404 for all the others.

I've been using an angular 2 prj. In the root dir I've got some files such as index.html, index1.html,main.ts and so on. That Angular prj was launched with node
(npm install -g @angular/cli, ng serve --open).

This error was obtained with any other file contained in the root that was not "index.html"

I've tried to explain better the environment in which occurs the issue. Are there any other necessary information to be provided?

Thank you so much

Comment: If you don't get answers for a question, don't just ask it again. **Edit** it to add more information. (Such as what web server you are using. What URLs are being requested by XHR (check in the Developer Tools Network tab to be sure). What happens if you request those URLs without using XHR. and so on).

Comment: can you please provide more code , how you are passing file is it array ???

Comment: What is the “target directory”, and where is it located in relation to the document this script is running in? It _can_ only be the same directory, right, because otherwise you would have to specify more than just a file name.

Comment: Regarding the tags on your second question: Is this an angular project you are talking about?

Comment: Thank so much to everyone.

Comment: I'll try to answer. I've been using an angular 2 prj. In the root dir I've got some files such as index.html, index1.html,main.ts and so on. That Angular prj was launched with node (npm install -g @angular/cli, ng serve --open).
I've tried to use this instruction: x= new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("get",'index.html',true) getting x.status=200 and  x.open("get",'index1.html',true) getting x.status=404. This error was obtained with any other file contained in the root that was not "index.html"